# Возможен ли переворот таблицы? Или возможен ли переворот данных в ней?

Tags: php

Хочу перевернуть таблицу, то есть изменить порядок строк на обратный.
Например взять 7 строк с конца.

Пример кода:

```
$count=10;
$count_news=0;

foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $key => $item)  
  {
    $count_news++;   
  }

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key => $item) {
  $i++;
  if ($i <= ($count_news-$count))
  {
    continue;
  }
  else
  {
    [тут делаем свои дела] // доп. - тут через print выводится таблица, построчно в каждой итерации.
    if($i == $count_news) break;
  }
}
```

Но как эти выводимые в таблицу записи перевернуть? У меня каждая итерация `foreach` делает строку таблицы в этом месте — `[тут делаем свои дела]`.
Вижу выход только в сборке массива, и его последующий реверс и вывод.

Если другие способы?

Comment: Кто-нибудь понял этот(ти) вопрос(ы)?

Comment: @Visman, если выкинуть все после слов "_Пример кода_", то становится более менее понятно

Comment: @I_CaR, что такое `$xml->channel->item` обычный массив или итератор?

Comment: Мне больше всего нравится фраза `здесь делаем свои дела`. По теме: сформулируйте вопрос точнее, действительно не понятно, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: `здесь делаем свои дела` там просто был вывод данных в таблицу. Примерно так `print "<tr><td><span class='text_news'>".mb_substr($item->children('yandex',true), 0, $count_simbols, 'utf-8')." [...]</span></td></tr>";`  
В ответе показал, как реализовал ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Они у тебя в базе хранятся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал так:

```
$count=10;
$count_news=0;

foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $key => $item)  
  {
    $count_news++;   
  }

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key => $item) {
  $i++;
  if ($i <= ($count_news-$count))
  {
    continue;
  }
  else
  {
    [здесь собирём массив: $content_array]
    if($i == $count_news) break;
  }
}

$content_array = array_reverse($content_array);

for ($x=0; $x<$count; $x++)
{
    print $content_array[$x];
}
```